# Image cannot be accessed from placehold.it in ionic with whitelist plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, whitelist

I am create very small demo in ionic with whitelist plugin. i take blank template and just take one image like below.

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
```

This will work in samsung mobile which have old os version 2.3.6 and this is not working in mi which have lollipop. I try following things

i am trying to add meta tag in index.html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

chrome mobile inspect give following error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

http://prntscr.com/8kmdjj.
```

In config.xml file origin is * means we can access any url with our application. like calling web services or other url 
`<access origin="*"/>`

But i cannot get any success. please help me for solving this. please